# Number of functions of $k$-arity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to find the number of possible functions $g_i$ acting on $k$ elements $(p_1,\dots,p_k)$ if the possible values of $p_j$s and $g_i$ are $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$.

My thoughts: $g_i:\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}^k\to\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$, $g_i:(p_1,\dots,p_k)\mapsto g_i(p_1,\dots,p_k)$. It's possible to imagine a tabular with each possible value of the input and so having in total $n^k$ rows. Now the values that $g_i$ can take are again between $n$ option for each row, and so I get $n^{kn}$ possible function. Is that true?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the task is: you have to calculate the cardinality of some subset $S\subseteq\{\text{functions }\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}^k\to \{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}\}$; a function $h$ is an element of $S$ if and only if *what*?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Nowhere in his question the OP talks about a subset. The OP want to calculate the size of the whole set of functions.

Comment: @jjagmath Ah, so the woth $(p_1,\cdots, p_k)$ stuff is just phoney baloney?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following

- $|A^k| = |A|^k$
- |$\{f:A \to B\}| = |B|^{|A|}$

In this case we have $|\{f:A^k \to A\}| = |A|^{|A^k|} = |A|^{|A|^k} = n^{n^k}$

Observe that this means $n^{(n^k)}$, not  $(n^n)^k = n^{nk}$